# intent anchor not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android app running happily on my Samsung S4, and a link to it in a web page. The link is successfully interpreted because the fallback page opens, but my app is not launched. Can someone spot the problem. Link and manifest below...

```
intent://#Intent;package=fr.notilus.DematAEAT_Android;action=AcquireSignedImage;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lemonde.fr;end

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="fr.notilus.DematAEAT_Android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="DematAEAT_Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="DematAEAT_Android" android:name="md5abda05033ab0415fc7a776c5d9734c74.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="AcquireSignedImage" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="fr.notilus.DematAEAT_Android.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.fr.notilus.DematAEAT_Android" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What makes you think your app should be opened? Why would Android open your app when this link is clicked?

Comment: [This page](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/) describes what I'm trying to do, and there's more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). The package name is specified in the link and the manifest, so that should be enough to let android execute the link.

Comment: No, the package name is not enough. You need to either specify an explicit Activity to start **or** you need to have an `<intent-filter>` in your manifest that matches the `Intent` you click on in the browser. You have neither :-(

Comment: I was working along those lines but I'm still stuck. I've updated the question. I now have an action in the manifest and the link, but still no joy.

Comment: Both of the links you provided use custom `scheme`s and the app has an `<intent-filter>` on one `Activity` that matches the custom `scheme`.

Comment: Your `<intent-filter>` doesn't match. You have a matching ACTION, but the data type does not match. It is way easier to do this using explicit classes.

Comment: Try removing the `data` part of your `<intent-filter>`.